# How can the concatenatation of a text and a NULL value return a non-null result?

Tags: postgresql, null, concat

#### Assert 1

The concatenation operator `||` can concatenate any string type values, returning `text`. In Postgres, every type has a text representation and can be cast to `text`. Consequently, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

> However, the string concatenation operator (`||`) still accepts non-string input, so long as at least one input is of a string type

Related:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943343/939860)

#### Assert 2

Concatenating one or more `NULL` values makes the result `NULL`.

```
test=# SELECT (text 'foo' || NULL) IS NULL
test-#      , (text 'bar' || char '1' || NULL ) IS NULL
test-#      , (NULL::bigint || text 'baz') IS NULL;
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 t        | t        | t
```

#### Question

Is it possible to concatenate a `text` and a `NULL` value and get a non-null result?

In other words, how is *this* possible?

```
test=# SELECT col IS NULL AS col_is_null
test-#     , (text 'foo' || col) IS NULL AS result_is_null
test-# FROM   tbl;
 col_is_null | result_is_null 
-------------+----------------
 t           | f
```

Applies to any Postgres version.
A client of mine stumbled over this, relying on the result to be `NULL`, and I found it intriguing enough to share.
It's a bit of a trick question as I know the answer.

<sub>**Note:** `CASE` or `COALESCE` catching `NULL` values are typically good style, but that's not what this question is about. It's about concatenation with an actual `NULL` value, with the concatenation operator `||` and still getting a non-null result.</sub>

Comment: is 'col' a string column?

Comment: @SQLRaptor: Good question. :) Turned out it's not a string type ...

Comment: I guess one of the non-standard types causes this behavior, but have no time to check :-)

Comment: Getting warm. :) It's really a "standard" type, though (as in: defined in the SQL standard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the system of CASTing array types in PostgreSQL is a bit weird (on a first sight) :-)

`text || text[]` makes both sides coerced to arrays.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (col text ARRAY);

INSERT INTO tbl SELECT NULL;

SELECT col IS NULL AS col_is_null,
  (text 'foo' || col) IS NULL AS result_is_null
  FROM tbl;

 col_is_null | result_is_null 
-------------+----------------
 t           | f
(1 row)
```

Another example which may shed more light:

```
create temp table x as select 'foo' test, null::text[] col; 
SELECT test, col, test || col from x;
 test | col  | ?column? 
------+------+----------
 foo  | NULL | {foo}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Spot on. You win the prize! :)

Comment: yea, made my day. have a nice weekend :-)

Comment: "makes both sides coerced to arrays" is very slightly off target, though. Operators are defined by operator *and* operands. Since one of the operands is a text  array (`text[]`) and the other `text`,  operator resolution arrives at the ["array-to-element" concatenation operator - or its sibling "element-to-array" with switched operands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) and adds the *element* to the *array*, and in this special case a `NULL` array is treated just like an empty array (`'{}'::text[]`) and the result is an array with one element.

Answer (score 0):

`Question
Is it possible to concatenate a text and a NULL value and get a non-null result?`

Answer, yes!

Using nested `CASE` [statements](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u6Ubb72JYMT84u7Um9PxMc/1) (with thanks to [Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778444/how-to-put-nested-case-when-condition-in-postgresql-query)):

```
CREATE TABLE null_test
(
  f1 TEXT,
  f2 INTEGER

);

INSERT INTO null_test VALUES ('foo', null);
INSERT INTO null_test VALUES (null, null);
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  '*_' || COALESCE(f1, '') || '_*' AS "Check",
  '*_' || 
  CASE 
    WHEN f2 IS NULL THEN
      CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(f2, 0) = 0 THEN ''
      END
   END || '_*' AS test_1,
  '*_' ||  
  COALESCE(f1, '') ||
  CASE 
    WHEN f2 IS NULL THEN
      CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(f2, 0) = 0 THEN ''
      END
   END || '_*' AS test_2,
   '*_' ||
   LENGTH
   (    
     COALESCE(f1, '') ||
     CASE 
       WHEN f2 IS NULL THEN
         CASE
           WHEN COALESCE(f2, 0) = 0 THEN ''
         END
     END
   ) || '_*' AS test_3     
FROM null_test;
```

Result (the `'*_` and `'_*'` are to make it more readily apparent what's going on!):

```
Check   test_1  test_2  test_3
*_foo_* *__*    *_foo_* *_3_*
*__*    *__*    *__*    *_0_*
```

Comment: Hmm, can't see a concatenation with NULL returning not-null here. (One can replace NULL with `COALESCE` or catch it with a `CASE` expression, but that's not what this question is about.)

Comment: How about [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u6Ubb72JYMT84u7Um9PxMc/6)? If I"m on the right track, I can write it up!

Comment: Nay, still cold! :)