# NULL value causes blank row in SELECT results for text concatenation

Tags: postgresql, select, null, concat

I have a query for producing some text for creating some VALUES text to put in a .sql file for inserting some rows. I get a blank line in the results:

```
postgres=# SELECT '  (' || obj_id || ', ''' || obj_type || '''),' FROM il2.objects WHERE obj_id < 11 ORDER BY obj_id;
        ?column?         
-------------------------
   (1, 'ScienceDomain'),

   (3, 'PIs'),
   (10, 'Instrument'),
(4 rows)
```

Doing a `select *`, it's pretty clear it's being caused by the `obj_type` being NULL for `obj_id` 2:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM il2.objects WHERE obj_id < 11;
 obj_id |   obj_type    
--------+---------------
     10 | Instrument
      1 | ScienceDomain
      2 | 
      3 | PIs
(4 rows)
```

(confirming it's NULL):

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM il2.objects WHERE obj_type IS NULL;
 obj_id | obj_type 
--------+----------
      2 |
```

Why is the result of the first `SELECT` giving me a blank row?
Even casting `obj_type::text` still gave me a blank row.

---

Additional Info:
The schema, for what it's worth:

```
postgres=# \d il2.objects
                                  Table "il2.objects"
  Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 obj_id   | integer           |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 obj_type | character varying |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "objects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (obj_id)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is the result of the first `SELECT` giving me a blank row?

Because concatenating `NULL` with any character type (or most other types, array types being a notable exception) results in `NULL`. Related:

- [How can the concatenatation of a text and a NULL value return a non-null result?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233522/how-can-the-concatenatation-of-a-text-and-a-null-value-return-a-non-null-result)

The representation of `NULL` depends on your client. Some spell out *`NULL`*, some (incl. psql) put *nothing* instead. Often that's configurable.

> Even casting `obj_type::text` still gave me a blank row.

Casting `NULL` to (almost) any type still returns `NULL` - of another data type.

> I have a query for producing some text for creating some `VALUES` text to put in a .sql file for inserting some rows.

Have you considered [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or the [psql equivalent `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)?

#### Other solutions

If your example isn't simplified, you might just select whole ROW values:

```
SELECT o  -- whole row
FROM   il2.objects o
WHERE  obj_id < 11
ORDER  BY obj_id;
```

If you need that specific format, use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to make it simple. Works with `NULL` values out of the box:

```
SELECT format('(%s, %L),', obj_id, obj_type)
FROM   objects;
```

You get *`NULL`* (unquoted) in place of `NULL` values (which is distinct from `''` and may have to be distinguishable.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f9f89e26c91d44f792a5169bdcab1bb6)* (added to the existing fiddle of McNets, kudos)

Comment: I didn't know about `format()` - nice.  I hadn't considered COPY; in a previous job, the convention was always to do inserts with the `VALUES` convention, but that's an excellent alternative, too - thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use COALESCE function to return the current value or an empty string.

```
SELECT '  (' || obj_id || ', ''' || coalesce(obj_type, '') || '''),' 
FROM   objects;
```

> ```
> | ?column?        |
> | :-------------- |
> |   (1, 'val 1'), |
> |   (2, ''),      |
> |   (3, 'val 3'), |
> |   (4, 'val 4'), |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5e634fbc6de9dcd606e2983a58fa803d)*